# InjectModel in a nestjs service does not work

Tags: typescript, mongodb, service, nestjs

I try to create a nestJs project.
I just want to do a CRUD API for some users.
Basically, an user will have a first name, a name, .... + a roleId and a list of friends (others users).
I also setted up a mongodb connexion.
To do that, I've tried to create a new folder called users.
here is my user-schema:

```
@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop()
  firstName: string;
  @Prop()
  lastName: string;
  @Prop()
  role: number;
  @Prop()
  age: number;
  @Prop()
  email: string;
  @Prop()
  password: string;
  @Prop({ type: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }] })
  friends: User[];
}
export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

user-interface:

```
export interface IUser extends Document {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  role: number;
  age: number;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  friends: User[];
}
```

user-module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
  ],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

app-module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(
      ' mongodb+srv://martin:martinmartin@cluster0.yd3p2xj.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
      {
        dbName: 'joy',
      },
    ),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and finally my user-service:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<IUser>) {}

  async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<IUser> {
    const createdUser = new this.userModel(createUserDto);
    return createdUser.save();
  }

  async findAll(): Promise<IUser[]> {
    return this.userModel.find().exec();
  }
}
```

I got an error in @InjectModel(User.name) ->The argument of type 'undefined' is not attributable to the parameter of type 'string | symbol'.

But I really followed the nestjs tutorial, I don't understand...

Can you help me ?

And have you any advices on the organization of my code ? Should we really create a DTO, an interface + a schema ? WHat's the need ? :)

Thanks guys !!

Tried to follow the nestjs tutorial

Comment: What are your versions of `@nestjs/common` and `typescript`?

Comment: Can you given the import statements for the user model inside the user-service. Can you check whether its correct?